# Best way to indicate network action

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

I'm developing news client and have some trouble with indication wile downloading data.
I have methods like folows:

```
    public async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        var src = CurrentSource;

        if (src != null && !src.IsLoading)
        {
            src.IsLoading = true;
            var uri = new Uri(GetFeedUri);
            try
            {
                var items = await _networkService.GetAsync<List<NewsItem>>(uri);
                _dispatcherService.SafeAction(() => src.Items.AddRange(items));
                await SaveSources();

                src.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _loggerService.LogMessage(NoInternetConnection, LoggerType.Error);
            }
            src.IsLoading = false;
        }
    }
```

The implementation of GetAsync:

```
    public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var http = WrappedHttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);
                var response = await http.GetAsync(uri, cancel.Token);
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<NetworkError>().Publish(true);
                    throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("No Internet connection. Code: {0}.", response.StatusCode));
                }
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<NetworkError>().Publish(false);
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<NetworkError>().Publish(true);
                throw new FileNotFoundException("No Internet connection.");
            }
        }
    }
```

WrappedHttpClient just adds headers to HttpClient.

IsLoading property is bind to ProgressBar on the view to indicate downloading and affect on commands (refresh, load more).

Most of time this code works great, but sometimes `src.IsLoading` do not switches to false and I dont know why. Is there other way to solve this problem? Or I do not consider some points? Please help.

Comment: The code you  pasted looks just fine to me.
Are you sure, your logger actually returns and the method completes? (As it is async, you might not even notice if the task is still sitting around somewhere.)

Comment: Logging isn't async. It is my custom service that stores a list of events. I suppose the problem is connected with network problems.

Comment: But your overall method (LoadAsync) is async. If nothing actually waits for it, you dont know if it really finishes. And it propably get's fired by some void returning event handler, so it's fire and forget. Just add some tracepoints to check and see what happens.

Comment: LoadAsync method is awaited in code. The problem is in this method. src.IsLoading sets to true, but in some cases do not sets back to false. And as a result I have ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate sets to true and disabled commands (reload, load more).

Comment: try with a finally block with `src.IsLoading = false;` in it